# Operator functions for built-in types

Tags: c++, operators

How can I explicitly use the underlying operator functions for operators defined for built-in types? See the code:

```
struct Int
{
    Int() = default;
    Int(int initial)
    {
        i = initial;
    }

    Int operator+(Int other)
    {
        return Int(i + other.i);
    }

    int i;
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Int& data)
{
    out << data.i;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    Int a, b = 5, c = 5;
    a = b + c;

    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    Int d, e = 5, f = 5;
    d.operator=(e.operator+(f));  // possible with user defined types

    std::cout << d << std::endl;

    int g, h = 5, j = 5;
    g.operator=(h.operator+(j));  // illegal

    return 0;
}
```

The part marked with 'illegal' produces the following error:

> request for member 'operator+' in 'h', which is of non-class type 'int'

I get it that you cannot invoke a method on an int, which is of non-class type. The question is where the meaning of the operator+ is defined and if it's possible to use it explicitly.

Comment: in the standard text :P

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: There *isn't* any "underlying" declarations for some types. They are just built into the compiler. You *can* use `x + y` in both cases, but the `x.operator+(y)` format only if the program has defined the operator as a member.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I explicitly use the underlying operator functions for operators defined for built-in types?

You can't.

If you are looking for a relevant part of the standard, then it should be:

> 16.5 Overloaded operators
>
> 6 An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or
>   be a non-member function that has at least one parameter whose type is
>   a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an
>   enumeration.